# Glitch: Google Drive API upload missing content

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, google-drive-api

I've been using Google Drive API v3 to insert/upload files to Google Drive folders without any problems.

Currently, I'm having problems with missing content of plain text `.txt` **files** contains multiple white spaces.

The files contain lines like this:

`H    12345  2018 # HELLO                     C-12345        mm/dd/yyyy          +0.00                                         K                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ID: 1234, Date: yyyy-mm-dd`

It only uploads **64KB** out of a **73KB** or lager file. However, and a big however, if I copy the same content of the same file and paste it in the file to make it about **2MB**, then it uploads the whole **2MB** file without any missing line. If I remove part of the file to make it smaller about **30 - 40MB** and it works fine.

I've checked:

- My `txt` file only contains data of a big string with spacing. So, there's no special character.
- I use a single function out of the code below to upload different file types and sizes and the function works without errors. So no problems from `async` or `Promise` functions in Javascript.

You can see my code here [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/vnndi/03ef2526a7df0c67a7081c9be3e2e548). It's basically Google Drive API code. I don't have any errors. I've looked for answers online without success. Google Drive API size limit is `10GB`. I wonder if this is a glitch of Google Drive API.

Have you experienced this problem? Do you know how to fix it?